# Type for function that recursively removes unnecessary container objects

Tags: typescript

I have objects being returned by a server that might contain container attributes.

Imagine an object like:

```
{
  attr1: string,
  attr2: number,
  attr3: {
    uselessArg1: ...,
    uselessArg2: ...,
    uselessArg3: ...,
    content: [subVal1, subVal2, ...]
  }
}
```

I have a function that would grab that object and return it like this:

```
{
  attr1: string,
  attr2: number,
  attr3: [subVal1, subVal2, ...]
}
```

Now, the real problem is that any object might have an attribute that has the object type with the useless keys and the `content` sub-attribute, including the objects in the `redundant` array

So we could imagine that any given object inherits from this interface:

```js
interface MaybeHasContent {
  [key:string]?: {
    uselessArg1: ...,
    uselessArg2: ...,
    uselessArg3: ...,
    content:this[]
  } 
}
```

My utility function first validates whether any key in the object has a `content` subkey, if found, hoists the value of the `content` subkey to its parent key, which clears all the useless attributes as well. Then it keeps calling itself on any child object of the current working object and also on any object inside the `content` array. It essentially runs through all the branches of an object, including branches that have object arrays, and hoists a very specific key one level up

How do I write an interface for this monster? I would like TS to understand that if I have an object where I can write `myObj.val1.redundant[0].name`, then after passing it through my utility function this would be a legal call: `myObj.val1[0].name`

Comment: I don't know why you want an interface for the input type, since it seems like just about any input value would be acceptable.  I'd have thought you'd want a utility type alias to compute the output type from the input type, so you could give a call signature to your utility function. That, I think, looks like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mx86Bm).  Does that meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Ah yeah, no, I don't care about the input type, I just care about the output. So for any given input that might have, somewhere in its downstream, an attribute that has the `content` attribute and its siblings, the content of `content` will be hoisted up. Yes, this is for the return type of a function, so the input type is less important

Comment: ... okay, and does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mx86Bm) work for you or not?

Comment: Sorry I was testing it to see how it behaved. Yes! this does it! Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one possible approach:

```
declare function clean<T>(t: T): Clean<T>;

type Clean<T> = T extends object ? (
    T extends { content: infer U } ?
    Clean<U> : { [K in keyof T]: Clean<T[K]> }
) : T;
```

Your function takes a value `t` of [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type `T`, and returns a value of type `Clean<T>`.

And `Clean<T>` is a [recursive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#recursive-conditional-types) representing what `clean()` does.  If `T` is of a [non-primitive `object` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-2.html#object-type), then we check to see if has a `content` property.  If so, we extract that property (using [conditional type `infer`ence](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types)) and pass it as the new type argument to `Clean`.  If not, then we [map](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) the object type `T` to a version where each property value has `Clean` applied to it.  (Note that this also takes care of array types, since [mapped types on arrays and tuples become arrays and tuples](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays).)  Finally, if `T` is a primitive type, we just return `T`.

---

Let's test it out:

```
const cleaned = clean({
    attr1: "abc",
    attr2: 123,
    attr3: {
        uselessArg1: 1,
        uselessArg2: 2,
        uselessArg3: 3,
        content: [
            { a: 1, b: 2, c: { content: "a", x: 1 } },
            { a: 3, b: 4, c: { content: "b", x: 2 } }
        ]
    }
});
/* const cleaned: {
    attr1: string;
    attr2: number;
    attr3: {
        a: number;
        b: number;
        c: string;
    }[];
} */
```

Looks good.  The type of `cleaned` is the same as the input type with all the `content` properties "hoisted up".  So `attr3` doesn't have the `uselessArg` properties.  It's just an array.  And the elements of that array have a `c` property that's just a `string`, because the `c` property of the input array had a `string`-valued `content` property itself.

---

There are always edge cases with such recursive type utilities. For example, it would be a bad idea if you tried to clean a pathologically recursive data structure:

```
interface ContentOuroboros {
    content: ContentOuroboros
}
type OhNoes = Clean<ContentOuroboros> // error!
// Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite.
```

I imagine you're not likely to do that, but it's hard for me to think of all possible pitfalls in advance.  So be sure to test it against your use cases and tweak if necessary.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=9&ssl=18&ssc=18&pln=17&pc=24#code/C4TwDgpgBAwgNhAhgOwDwBUB8UC8V1QQAewEyAJgM5QD2ARgFYQDGwUA-FABQBQU-+QiTJUoAbyjMayUjIBcUAJbIAZhABOUAKpQAvhz4D4SNFuwKJAbQDSS5FADWEEDRX4AuguMoMN99l0eAEooBXQAbh4eFQBXZFZFaUkEHywuYDCgrxS0LEjY+OBE+2Yc9IUUEBCxQ35FNy4AQmAQ9QhgGPV7YEiBJQbQSFcoNkacPAAieiZWCdb2zu7egXruCakZMmAJuxH5jq7kk3SAOg3ZFuW6hoBBdXVEEBPFSjuHkHSg-cWRk4BbRBgLilExBK5QNoHewAeUYLGAJxU6hofwAojJ1IoIJReH0+rCZgitpjsZ9-oCuFxLA4ADRQABu7hCOGw1LpIJQXHpQSZtSgYJ4gR4G0obA5yAg5FwR05NT6iGAwHUAEYFBNEHRmBMaXyFUqAEwKZX6gDMOvlivUJosfL6MUoEAQlFe6gA5qqoMrzXj+PbHdiXa7DVB9d6fX6nYHrVAzbaBOctgpLHGfRJEEa6XQFKHJBZJNILmrENqoEQjXo9GGfQI0wozVAs1AACzsvMJ+RQCZ0EtlkMVwLVqDuPmBXQCgD0ACp88hRTKJeQbRalR7RZjkK7wXr1MHkDE-nQNFvLdG5dX01A9wejymGwor4f1OC+swFGvlJuR5Z3JF9JPx1EwrSJQNAICccA0K6wI5JKQRAbOoEQOBkHQSYkonNuJrkkCRC4NgRBnCcwA0FoYCQOoMCIA6XBfCcDA0MoXAlnMYJQOO46djcdIAEITIByikOoKiIMw0AwAWWzQp09A0Mi1Bnvw7YZLAEkyFJyJ0LJNCUIKPCDNA0IABYAHI0Ni0reGg4mbGp0maXJ2DsYQ9yyY0PBOeg4DQMooooEUCrFEo1DEKJzqKPSjogFA5AQBAYBQCgUpgNplCKHQcBRcoKjKIopAnFw+oAKwABwAJxBEAA)